# AngularJS: How to have different Services/Controllers in same Module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have a Service and a controller in my AngularJS App, that should be in the same module, but are two different files:

```
// File 1 (Service)
angular.module('myService', ['ngRoute'])
.service('myService', // ... 


// File 2 (Controller)
angular.module('myController', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('myController', // ..
```

This works fine. Now I want to have Service & Controller in one Module so I can load just one instead of two Modules. So I change the first line (of both files) to:

```
// Change in both files:
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])
```

But now I get an error:

*Error: [$injector:unpr] ...*

Maybe somebody knows, what could be wrong here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("myService"

myApp.service("myApp")
```

Or

```
angular.module("myModule").controller

angular.module("myModule").service
```

If you use angular.module('myService', []) twice, you are initializing the same module twice.
If you just use angular.module("myModule"), without the dependencies, you are just calling it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Michael. Your first snippet: I have to use line 1 (very MyApp = ....) twice (in both files), right? Your second snippet: Where do I declare the Module "myModule"? Or can I just use it, without declaring it?

Comment: If a variable in the first script is visible in the second script, you can initialize the module in the first one.
Just to see how it could be:
-first approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/yfvrjxve/
-second approach
http://jsfiddle.net/yfvrjxve/3/

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, it works perfect (I use the second approach). :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options -

1. use a variable as mentioned by Michael

OR

2. Use it like -

```html
// Initialize myService Module in any JS file 
   (make sure this file is included before File 1 and File 2
angular.module('myService', ['ngRoute']);

// File 1 (Service)
angular.module('myService').service('myService', // ... 

// File 2 (Controller)
angular.module('myService').controller('myController', // ..
```